# android ListView с кнопками. Как получить _id строки, на которой кликнута кнопка

Tags: java, android

В общем есть список `ListView`, который я заполняю через `SimpleCursorAdapter`.
Инициализируется вот так:

```
String[] from = new String[] {"client_tel","timeToWashStart"};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.client_tel,R.id.timeToWashStart};


scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this);
```

Данные получаю через `CursorLoader` с `MySQL`, список формируется, все нормально.
Но в каждой строке списка есть кнопки, на которые нужно кликать.

**Вот сам вопрос:** как узнать _id или позицию строки, где была кликнута кнопка?

причем метод

```
lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "position = " + position + " id= " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

почему-то не работает...
и я никак не пойму как прописать метод `getView()` для адаптера.

Скажите в какую сторону думать, я уже запарился на месте топтаться)
Заранее благодарен за советы

ПС: весь код у меня реализован в одном классе, может это важно

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что не работает setOnItemClickListener, можно только догадываться. Выгрузите код, тогда будет ответ.

Узнать позицию и id при нажатии на кнопку (cursorloader), можно разными вариантами, самый очевидный и простой на мой взгляд:

---

Делаем кастомный SimpleCursorAdapter, находим нашу кнопку, вешаем слушатель. Далее получаем его родителя (элемент в списке) у этого элемента получаем родителя это и есть наш список и относительно их находим позицию в списке. Зная позицию получаем id:

### MyAdapter.class

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View parent_row = (View) v.getParent();
            ListView lv = (ListView) parent_row.getParent();
            final int position = lv.getPositionForView(parent_row);

            Log.d("...", "position = " + position);
            Log.d("...", "id = " + getItemId(position));
        }
    });
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
   }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, действительно надо было вынести в отдельный класс и переопределить bindView. Что интересно, у меня на каждой каждой кнопке был записан onClick и они оба работают независимо

Answer (score 1):

Если подытожить, рабочий кусок кода:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    public String LOG_TAG = "LOG_TAG";
    public ListView lvData;
    public MyAdapter scAdapter;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);

 ///попробую тут адаптер инициализировать
String[] from = new String[] {"client_tel","timeToWashStart"};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.client_tel,R.id.timeToWashStart};

Log.d(LOG_TAG,"формируем адаптер");
// создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
///  scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
scAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

// создаем лоадер для чтения данных 
 http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html
// по этой ссылке описано что делает следующая строка, это получение данных
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this);
}
```

И, как рекомендовал `shwarz-andrei`, создаем отдельный класс для адаптера

> ```
> public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
> public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
>     super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
>     final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
>     img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             View parent_row = (View) v.getParent();
>             ListView lv = (ListView) parent_row.getParent();
>             final int position = lv.getPositionForView(parent_row);
>
>             Log.d("...", "position = " + position);
>             Log.d("...", "id = " + getItemId(position));
>         }
>     });
>     super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
>    }
> }
> ```